# Redis-stat is not found

Tags: ruby, redis, rubygems

I wanted to use `redis-stat` to monitor my redis server. I checked out [redis-stat](https://github.com/junegunn/redis-stat), started redis-stat, and got an error:

```
$./redis-stat localhost:6379 1 10
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- redis-stat (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from ./redis-stat:4:in 'main'
```

How can I handle this problem? I have the following information:

```
$ruby -v
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-linux]

$gem -v
2.2.2

$which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby

$which gem
/usr/local/bin/gem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I checked out redis-stat

What do you mean by "checked out"? Did you clone the git repository?
redis-stat is supposed to be installed using gem command like so:

```
gem install redis-stat
```

Then you should be able to start it with `redis-stat` without `./` prefix.

Comment: yes, I clone the git repo, the homepage said that it can also be started the service with ./redis-stat in 'redis-stat/bin/',

Comment: @user4100935 No, it doesn't. Which paragraph are you referring to? (I'm the maintainer of the project)

Comment: As for my way, I saw it from a blog(published in 2013.10), may be starting with 'bin/redis-stat' belongs to old version of redis-stat.

Comment: Okay, however, even [the initial version of the README page](https://github.com/junegunn/redis-stat/blob/73de1b7c569214e143877e100f8d4a35d5667b68/README.md) stated that it should be installed via `gem install` command. Looks like the blog post contains incorrect information.